# continuous functions: extremal properties

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Please help me with this question.

Let $f : R → R$ be a continuous function that is periodic in the sense that for some number $p$, $f(x + p) = f(x)$
for all $x ∈ R$. Show that $f$ has an absolute maximum and an absolute minimum.

Comment: Its the fourth question you open without showing any of your effort and just imposing problems. Please try before asking, if you can't solve, write here what you did, you will learn more this way.

Answer (score 1):

Since $[x,x+p]$ is compact and $f$ continuous, it has a local max on the interval, say $r$. Then it is a global max because of the periodicity.

Answer (score 0):

- Show that $f(\mathbb{R})=f([0,p])$ (periodicity)
- Show that $f$ has a maximum and minimum (that it reaches) on $[0,p]$ (continuity — extreme value theorem)